# AttributeError: 'CloudWatchLogHandler' object has no attribute 'shutting_down' while deploying django-rest-api into aws

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

i have deployed my django-rest-api application into aws using zappa. its working fine but sometimes i'm getting error like AttributeError: 'CloudWatchLogHandler' object has no attribute 'shutting_down'(im using watchtower for logging in aws).please help me out

```
in settings.py for logs :


from boto3.session import Session
import logging
boto3_session = Session(aws_access_key_id=S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                        aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                        region_name=S3_REGION)
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    # 'root': {
        # 'level': logging.ERROR,
        # 'handlers': ['console'],
    # },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': u"%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'aws': {
            # you can add specific format for aws here
            'format': u"%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'watchtower': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler',
                     'boto3_session': boto3_session,
                     'log_group': 'test_logs_group',
                     'stream_name': 'test_stream_name',
            'formatter': 'aws',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['watchtower'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        # add your other loggers here...
    },
}
```

i kept that code in settings.py for logging using watchtower in cloudwatch

Comment: It seems a bug in Watchtower itself.

As you're new here, some hints that we can help you better:

* Add the stacktrace or full error message.
* Add references to the software & documentation.
* Keep credits if you use code from others. E.g. the code in your question is from [Watchtower's repository Readme](https://github.com/kislyuk/watchtower#example-django-logging-with-watchtower).

Answer (score 0):

This will fail when your connection to CloudWatch is invalid - probably an issue with your AWS Access Key or permissions.